# Aspose cell exception:om.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader cannot be cast to com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader

Tags: java, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

I am using Aspose.Cells (trial version) to parse a .xls (Excel) file for Java. But when I try to load the file, it throws the exception given below:

> SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: XML Stream Exception: XMLStreamException: com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader cannot be cast to com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader

Here is my code

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
try {
  workbook.open(path+fileName);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
```

This exception is coming at **`workbook.open(path+fileName);`** this line.I am quiet sure that this is not due to wrong path because when I give wrong path then aspose throws `FileNotFoundException`.So now I am stuck here and unable to find why this is happening?
**Note:** In search of this problem, I found [this answer](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/342468/342468/showthread.aspx) on aspose forum but it is not helpful and feasible(to check all the classes present in jars placed in lib).

Comment: Can you please share the input XLS file as it seems to be an issue related to the particular file. You may share the file directly in Aspose.Cells product support forum. http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx

Comment: Can you please share with us which version of aspose cell are you using? 2ndly are you using it directly in plain java code or in any web app?

Answer (score 0):

We recommend you to kindly try our latest version of the product (e.g v7.7.x (JAVA)) as we did  remove some inter dependencies jars and have written/included our own custom XML parsers to perform some XML operations in the product. In the new versions, we we have removed the conflicting "com.etc.wstx" jar in the product, so you should not find this exception any more.

Thanks,