# com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader cannot be cast to com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader

Tags: java, aspose, aspose-cells

When I am trying to convert a `xlsx` file into `pdf` using this code

```
 else if (extension.equals("xlsx"))
        {
            //Createing and XLSX LoadOptions object
            LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions(FileFormatType.XLSX);

            //Creating an Workbook object with 2007 xlsx file path and the loadOptions object
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook(Path, loadOptions);
            workbook.save(destPath, FileFormatType.PDF);
            System.out.println("XLSX executed");
        }
```

I am getting this exception

```
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: XML Stream Exception: XMLStreamException: com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader cannot be cast to com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader
    at com.aspose.cells.a.c.z.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.a.c.z.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.re.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.mn.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.mn.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.mn.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.mm.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.Workbook.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.delta.MiDAS.commonlibs.Utility.convertExcel(Utility.java:132)
    at com.delta.MiDAS.controllers.DocumentInsertController.loadDocForPreview(DocumentInsertController.java:510)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: XMLStreamException: com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader cannot be cast to com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader
    at com.aspose.cells.b.a.h.k.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.b.a.h.k.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.b.a.h.k.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.cells.b.a.h.k.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader cannot be cast to com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader
    ... 61 more
```

I am using `aspose-cells-7.3.4.jar` for conversion.Is it due to trial version or something else?

**Edit:** I have found form the stacktrace that exception is coming on this line `Workbook workbook = new Workbook(Path, loadOptions);`. Also I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805975/aspose-cell-exceptionom-ctc-wstx-sr-validatingstreamreader-cannot-be-cast-to-co) having problem exactly like me but unforunatly it is still unanswered

Comment: What type of environment do you use (e.g. application server)? It looks like you have a problem with your class loaders.

Comment: yes I am using this in a web application.I am using glassfish server

Comment: @UwePlonus this line is throwing the exception `Workbook workbook = new Workbook(Path, loadOptions);`